# Saving a Pandas data frame as CSV or XLSX in a more readable fashion

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe (shape 40x2; two rows are shown below):

> Honduras ['Water\nAgriculture\nHealth\nBiodiversity and... 
>   Hungary   ['not explicitly mentioned']

I would like to get rid off list signs [, ] and quotation ' sign so that it is saved in csv or xlsx in the following form:

> Honduras  Water,
>             Agriculture,
>             Health,
>             Biodiversity and...
>
> Hungary  not explicitly mentioned

Thank you very much.

Best,
Sharif

Comment: You can try `.replace()`.  As in: `pd.replace(']','').replace('[','').replace('\'', '')`

Answer (score 0):

Considering only first row but you can apply this all rows of your dataframe,

```
l1 = "Honduras ['Water\nAgriculture\nHealth\nBiodiversity']"
l1 = l1.replace(']', '').replace('[', '').replace("'", '').replace(' ', '')
l1 = l1.split('\n')
l1
```

Output:

```
['HondurasWater', 'Agriculture', 'Health', 'Biodiversity']
```

Note: After applying to all rows, you will get list for each row and now you can convert these lists to dataframe and then write to `csv`.